# hi I have six month UK tourist visa. coming may I plan to visit London.

Tags: visas, amsterdam

In case I want visit Amsterdam. How I get visa in London is it possible?

Comment: Extremely unclear what you're asking...

Comment: @MeNoTalk, he's asking how to apply for a Schengen after he has landed in the UK.

Comment: What is your citizenship?  Although this may be irrelevant, because, if you need a visa to visit UK, you most likely will need one to visit a Schengen country.  The main point is that you normally cannot apply for a Schengen visa from a country other than your country of citizenship or your country of residence.